# Custom AppBar Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Im trying to achieve something like the following, 
[image]

I'm very new to flutter so I couldn't figure it out.
I need a custom AppBar with drawer and actions but arranged like the image.

I tried a StackView in the title widget

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: CustomColors.accentColor,
        ),
        Text(
          'Title',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, color: CustomColors.primaryDark),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

But I get something like this
[image]

Can someone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: it's not a custom AppBar , it's just a custom widget

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment , you can create a Custom widget like your Image attached, there are many ways to do it, this is just an example :

```
    class CustomBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {

      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body: Container(
            height: 160.0,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Home",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 80.0,
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                    child: DecoratedBox(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5), width: 1.0),
                          color: Colors.white),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              print("your menu action here");
                              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                            },
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Search",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              print("your menu action here");
                            },
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.notifications,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              print("your menu action here");
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

For more information, I wrote an article about how we can customize the `AppBar` :
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the code. I was able to create a custom widget with similar design. The reason I specifically said as AppBar is because I need to retain the functionality of an AppBar like changing to back icon on navigation, controlling drawer. I can recreate all the functionalities but since AppBar is a widget can we customize it?

Comment: Thanks for the code, that helps me start on my replacement for the AppBar because I cannot get the AppBar to do what I need. I need the AppBar toolbar height to be greater than 56, and that currently cannot be done. The overall height of the AppBar can be changed, but by increasing it does not allow the height of the AppBar toolbar to be increased beyond 56. This is referenced partly by Flutter issues #7330 and #23373.

Comment: @BrianOh I wrote an article about that: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f

Answer (score 52):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

- **Using `flexibleSpace`**

  ```dart
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 120, // Set this height
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('One'),
            Text('Two'),
            Text('Three'),
            Text('Four'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```
- **Using `PreferredSize`**

  ```dart
  Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120), // Set this height
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('One'),
            Text('Two'),
            Text('Three'),
            Text('Four'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: This is ok only if you want to overlap the statusbar

Answer (score 18):

Just wrap whole thing in **Stack**. Then AppBar in Positioned as last widget and in between some widget (Eg. Container) so AppBar can float above them.

[image: Custom AppBar using official AppBar only]

```
 Widget setPage() {
    Color red800 = Colors.red[800];

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(     // Background
          child: Center(
             child: Text("Home", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.white),),),
          color: red800,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),

        Container(),   // Required some widget in between to float AppBar

        Positioned(    // To take AppBar Size only
          top: 100.0,
          left: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: red800,),
            primary: false,
            title: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: red800), onPressed: () {},),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: red800),
                onPressed: () {},)
            ],
          ),
        )

      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 18):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code (Null Safe):**

For simplicity, I didn't create the desired UI, I just wanted to show you how you can create a custom app bar with `PreferredSize`

Create this class:

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double height;

  CustomAppBar({
    required this.child,
    this.height = kToolbarHeight,
  });

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: preferredSize.height,
      color: Colors.orange,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Usage:**

Use it like any other `AppBar` but this time you can set `height` property:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: CustomAppBar(
    height: 120,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('One'),
        Text('Two'),
        Text('Three'),
        Text('Four'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I created it with Stack and PreferredSize for AppBar. Using this allow us to reuse default AppBar properties like having the AppBar sticky at the top of the screen when we have a ListView in the body.

```
_appBar(height) => PreferredSize(
    preferredSize:  Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height+80 ),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(     // Background
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Home", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.white),),),
          color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          height: height+75,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),

        Container(),   // Required some widget in between to float AppBar

        Positioned(    // To take AppBar Size only
          top: 100.0,
          left: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
            primary: false,
            title: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor), onPressed: () {},),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                onPressed: () {},)
            ],
          ),
        )

      ],
    ),
  );
```

Inside the scaffold, we just call the above for appbar. We want to pass in the AppBar().preferredSize.height as the default appBar height is different across different devices (eg: iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone 11 Pro Max).

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
      body: ListView(),
    );
})
```

[image]