# How can I make this custom app bar in flutter(android)?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, flutter-layout, mobile-application

I am trying to create a android **tab bar** like this image [custom tab bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGKkM.jpg) in flutter.
How can I make a tab bar like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many examples for your questions you can check the links. Also appbar is a widget on the top of the screen and has buttons. You can create a buttons in the scaffold widget and put them top of the screen still same but easy to decorate and use.

[Custom AppBar Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658208/custom-appbar-flutter)

[Custom AppBar](https://dev.to/pazozzoo/creating-a-custom-appbar-in-flutter-572k)