# A Custom Appbar Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

Im trying to achieve something like the following,
[image]

I'm very new to flutter so I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658208/custom-appbar-flutter

Comment: @A.S.H I want a wavy appbar

Comment: Look into this. https://github.com/therajanmaurya/Wave-AppBar

Comment: @Friedrick Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appbar in flutter is usually fixed. You can make a work around. Add a default appbar and just below, add another custom widget from the link given

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers