# what is the best way to implement this home screen?

Tags: flutter, homescreen

I would like to create a home page for my flutter app. I used templates from the network, but unfortunately I don't get it the way I sketched it in the picture. maybe someone can help me with that

[sketch / result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/citfd.jpg)

Unfortunately, I'm sure that I can't do it better: - /, would like to have it exactly like the one on the left (icons and colors are not so important)

I used this link from the forum as a template for the appbar, and I had difficulties in inserting it ^^
[Custom AppBar Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658208/custom-appbar-flutter)

I also got the code for the BottomNavigationBar from somewhere in the forum, but I think this is not suitable for my purposes anyway. Since I don't like this shrink effect when clicking on it, the two arrow buttons at the edge should snap back when pressed and not stay in the pressed state, as they should stand for the front and back function ...

here is my complete main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Color(0xFF34445c),
          primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
          canvasColor: Color(0xFFCECECE),
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light)),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColorLight: Colors.black,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          canvasColor: Colors.black,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark)),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _selectedItemColor = Colors.white;
  final _unselectedItemColor = Colors.white30;
  final _selectedBgColor = Color(0xFF293749);
  final _unselectedBgColor = Color(0xFF34445c);
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: ZURÜCK',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: FAVORITES',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: KOMMENTARE / LÖSCHEN',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 3: ABOUT-US',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 4: WEITER',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Color _getBgColor(int index) =>
      _selectedIndex == index ? _selectedBgColor : _unselectedBgColor;

  Color _getItemColor(int index) =>
      _selectedIndex == index ? _selectedItemColor : _unselectedItemColor;

  Widget _buildIcon(IconData iconData, String text, int index) => Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
    child: Material(
      color: _getBgColor(index),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(iconData),
            Text(text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: _getItemColor(index))),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () => _onItemTapped(index),
      ),
    ),
  );

  _appBar(height) => PreferredSize(
    preferredSize:  Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height+80 ),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text("TEXT", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: Colors.white),
            ),

          ),
          color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          height: height+75,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
        Container(
        ),
        Positioned(    // To take AppBar Size only
          top: 100.0,
          left: 20.0,
          right: 20.0,
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF293749),
            leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white),
            primary: false,
            title: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 0.0, left: 0.0),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 5.0, left: 5.0),
                child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Suchen",
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white), onPressed: () {},),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedFontSize: 0,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _buildIcon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded, 'ZURÜCK', 0),
            title: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _buildIcon(Icons.favorite, 'FAVORITEN', 1),
            title: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _buildIcon(Icons.comment, 'KOMMENTARE', 2),
            title: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _buildIcon(Icons.info_outline_rounded, 'ÜBER UNS', 3),
            title: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _buildIcon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded, 'WEITER', 4),
            title: SizedBox.shrink(),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: _selectedItemColor,
        unselectedItemColor: _unselectedItemColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code with some commentaries to support you in building the UI.

For the `AppBar`, you are going in the right direction of using `PreferredSize` with `Stack`, just some minor adjustments.

For the `BottomNavigationBar`, since the provided `BottomNavigationBarItem` has the `icon` and `title` attributes already, we can use that and modify the color from their parents. The 2 arrows buttons can be placed together within the `Row`.

Here's the full example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Color(0xFF34445c),
          primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
          canvasColor: Color(0xFFCECECE),
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.light)),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColorLight: Colors.black,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.black,
          indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          canvasColor: Colors.black,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(brightness: Brightness.dark)),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _selectedItemColor = Colors.white;
  final _unselectedItemColor = Colors.white30;
  final _selectedBgColor = Color(0xFF293749);
  final _unselectedBgColor = Color(0xFF34445c);
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal);

  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: ZURÜCK',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: FAVORITES',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: KOMMENTARE / LÖSCHEN',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 3: ABOUT-US',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 4: WEITER',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  _appBar() => PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(300),
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Color(0xFF34445D),
                height: 180,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "APP TITLE",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: List<Widget>.generate(
                        4,
                        (index) => Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                          child: Icon(Icons.people, color: Colors.white), // Sample icons for demonstration
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 150.0,
                left: 20.0,
                right: 20.0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Color(0xFF293749),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          height: 30,
                          child: TextField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Search...',
                                border: InputBorder.none),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: _selectedBgColor,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex =
                      _selectedIndex <= 0 ? _selectedIndex : _selectedIndex - 1;
                });
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, // Add the type here to avoid auto resize
                backgroundColor: _selectedBgColor, // You can also set the unselectedBackgroundColor
                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index), // Update the selected index
                selectedItemColor: _selectedItemColor,
                unselectedItemColor: _unselectedItemColor,
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('FAVORITEN')),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.comment), title: Text('KOMMENTARE')),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
                      title: Text('ÜBER UNS')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, color: Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex =
                      _selectedIndex >= 2 ? _selectedIndex : _selectedIndex + 1;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great to know man, would love to know your progress with the app!